# find location of hotels with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with scraping the hotel location from this [link](https://www.cvent.com/venues/en-US/dubai/hotel/jw-marriott-marquis-hotel-dubai/venue-c6d701db-da99-4133-a3de-608d446d3446?aCode=D7NNVHN7TCT&geo=eJx9UF1rwjAU_Sslz66kaZKmvtWPiQ_qQGW-SdpGG0gTSVNQpP99ycZ0IOzpwrnn4557BydjW-6cqLeC26rZiasDYzDrSy6jt2ivpV9FheVlNG-l5U50YASkhyVXC2HOll8aWb1L5YT1wslmv54t14vjZHPwxNL0upb6PDHXX8oduNtF_EsNJG2sa-a8cx9GahcQxf1AJE4JIxRSiijJGR0BZTQYExITiglKSIZwAhEdRqAzvWs-xYsFjrM8xQwnjOQQ4YcFjlkOMcEpIjCHEA-DNzk_On67vLRYFYflar86zpbbXbGezn2Tll9l27dgnLzI__ZA0N-Qp88CKIMZQyykVkafZC2CwNleBKDXzt6mpg6hRYjp_LOUKOraiq7b_VyjTMWVdDcwfAG8RJXo).

The structure of the element is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saXNm.png)

I wrote this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.cvent.com/venues/en-US/dubai/hotel/jw-marriott-marquis-hotel-dubai/venue-c6d701db-da99-4133-a3de-608d446d3446?aCode=D7NNVHN7TCT&geo=eJx9UF1rwjAU_Sslz66kaZKmvtWPiQ_qQGW-SdpGG0gTSVNQpP99ycZ0IOzpwrnn4557BydjW-6cqLeC26rZiasDYzDrSy6jt2ivpV9FheVlNG-l5U50YASkhyVXC2HOll8aWb1L5YT1wslmv54t14vjZHPwxNL0upb6PDHXX8oduNtF_EsNJG2sa-a8cx9GahcQxf1AJE4JIxRSiijJGR0BZTQYExITiglKSIZwAhEdRqAzvWs-xYsFjrM8xQwnjOQQ4YcFjlkOMcEpIjCHEA-DNzk_On67vLRYFYflar86zpbbXbGezn2Tll9l27dgnLzI__ZA0N-Qp88CKIMZQyykVkafZC2CwNleBKDXzt6mpg6hRYjp_LOUKOraiq7b_VyjTMWVdDcwfAG8RJXo')
link_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@title, "Open this area in Google Maps")]/@href')
print(link_element.get_attribute('value'))
```

but it gives an error:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: yes. I also use WebDriverWait but can't fix it!

Comment: Change your userAgent to mimic a mobile device and make the browser window smaller, otherwise that element won't appear. And use Waits().

Comment: I new to Selenium, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code, as I checked it works.

```py
driver.get('https://www.cvent.com/venues/en-US/dubai/hotel/jw-marriott-marquis-hotel-dubai/venue-c6d701db-da99-4133-a3de-608d446d3446?aCode=D7NNVHN7TCT&geo=eJx9UF1rwjAU_Sslz66kaZKmvtWPiQ_qQGW-SdpGG0gTSVNQpP99ycZ0IOzpwrnn4557BydjW-6cqLeC26rZiasDYzDrSy6jt2ivpV9FheVlNG-l5U50YASkhyVXC2HOll8aWb1L5YT1wslmv54t14vjZHPwxNL0upb6PDHXX8oduNtF_EsNJG2sa-a8cx9GahcQxf1AJE4JIxRSiijJGR0BZTQYExITiglKSIZwAhEdRqAzvWs-xYsFjrM8xQwnjOQQ4YcFjlkOMcEpIjCHEA-DNzk_On67vLRYFYflar86zpbbXbGezn2Tll9l27dgnLzI__ZA0N-Qp88CKIMZQyykVkafZC2CwNleBKDXzt6mpg6hRYjp_LOUKOraiq7b_VyjTMWVdDcwfAG8RJXo')     
button_element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[text()="Nearby"]')    
button_element.click()    
time.sleep(3)    
link_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@title, "Open this area in Google Maps")]')    
print(link_element.get_attribute('href'))
```